# How to make multiple tables in single csv file in node js?

Tags: node.js, csv, export-to-csv

I want to export data as csv file. I want to make multiple tables in single csv file but not getting a way for doing the same in node.js. Can anybody help to fix it out?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple tables can be exported to a single csv file by making use of the property `title` in the `options` that is passed as a parameter to `ExportToCsv`.

step 1: Let's get the csv equivalent of the first table to be inserted into the csv file.

```
    var data_one = [ // Table one data to be represented as csv
       {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Vinayak",
        "age": 33
       },
       {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Ganesh",
        "age": 28
       },
       {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Sundar",
        "age": 45
       }
      ];

  const table_one_options = {  // Table one options
  fieldSeparator: ',',
  quoteStrings: '"',
  decimalSeparator: '.',
  showLabels: true,
  showTitle: true,
  title: 'Two table Report',
  filename: 'GenerateCSV',
  useTextFile: false,
  useBom: true,
  useKeysAsHeaders: true};

  const csvExporter_one = new ExportToCsv(table_one_options);
  var table_one_csv = csvExporter_one.generateCsv(data_one, true);  // Here pass 'true' as the second parameter in order to obtain only the csv and not to download the csv file
```

From the above code we have obtained the csv equivalent of the table_one in the variable `table_one_csv`

Step 2: Now this csv goes as the title to the second instance of `ExportToCsv`

```
   var data_two =  [  // Table two data to be represented as csv
    {
      name: 'Test 1',
      age: 13,
      average: 8.2,
      approved: true,
      description: "Description A"
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 2',
      age: 11,
      average: 8.2,
      approved: true,
      description: "Description B"
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 4',
      age: 10,
      average: 8.2,
      approved: true,
      description: "Description C"
    },
  ];

  const table_two_options = {  // Table two options
  fieldSeparator: ',',
  quoteStrings: '"',
  decimalSeparator: '.',
  showLabels: true,
  showTitle: true,
  title: table_one_csv,  // table_one_csv obtained in step 1.
  filename: 'GenerateCSV',
  useTextFile: false,
  useBom: true,
  useKeysAsHeaders: true};

  const csvExporter_two = new ExportToCsv(table_two_options);
  csvExporter_two.generateCsv(data_two);
```

This results in the following csv file `GenerateCSV.csv`

[image: GenerateCSV.csv]

This way multiple tables can be added in a single csv file using `export-to-csv`

Refer to [export-to-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/export-to-csv) for complete description of `export-to-csv` npm package

Hope this helps!